# How to add AdMob ads?

Tags: java, android, admob

I've been following this tutorial (http://www.kilobolt.com/day-7-creating-an-android-game-from-start-to-finish.html) for creating an Android game. Now I would like to add AdMob ads to the game in `GameScreen` Class inside `private void drawGameOverUI() {...}`.

I got the context from  `SampleGame` Class using

```
private static Context context;
public Screen getInitScreen() {
        SampleGame.context = getApplicationContext();
...
}
public static Context getAppContext() {
        return SampleGame.context;
}
```

In `GameScreen` Class inside `private void drawGameOverUI()` I have this

```
contextGameScreen = SampleGame.getAppContext();
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(contextGameScreen);    
adView = new AdView(contextGameScreen, AdSize.BANNER, "...");
layout.addView(adView);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

but I got this error `"Cannot resolve constructor 'AdView(android.content.Context, com.google.ads.AdSize, java.lang.String)'"` for `(contextGameScreen, AdSize.BANNER, "...");`.

On Google Developers (https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#android) they use 'this', but when I use `(this, AdSize.BANNER, "...");` I got the error `"Cannot resolve constructor 'AdView(com.name.GameScreen, com.google.ads.AdSize, java.lang.String)'"`.

Can you please help me with this, how to solve this error, and to get this to work? This means alot to me. And also what exactly is 'this'?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that contextGameScreen in

```
new AdView(contextGameScreen, AdSize.BANNER, "...")
```

is not an instance of android.content.Context. Eg an Activity or an Application.

It is very hard to work out exactly what you are doing as you have only provided disconnected scraps of code, but what you need to do is to provide the AdView constructor the Activity in which in will be embedded.

Comment: Do you know how should I do that? Whole code is on first link that I posted. On that page is SampleGame Class, GameScreen Class and everything else. I could copy all that and post here, but since the post would be to large, I just posted a link to the whole code.

Comment: Well according that that article "This SampleGame class extends AndroidGame class (which extends Activity), and therefore is an Activity.", so you should be able to pass in an instance of SampleGame.

Comment: I passed the context from SampleGame, but that's not working. Could you give me advice how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: According to the doco for the library you are using SampleGame IS an Activity. So pass in SampleGame.